# How to write json files to bigquery using apache-beam?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Hi have a text file containing json,that I want to write in BQ.
Following are content of file:

```
{"id":1,"name":"A","status":"ACTIVE"}
{"id":2,"name":"B","status":"ACTIVE"}
{"id":3,"name":"C","status":"ACTIVE"}
```

Below is my code,to write files to BQ.

```
table_schema = {
  "fields": [
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "id",
      "type": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "name",
      "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "status",
      "type": "STRING"
    }
  ]
}



import apache_beam as beam
import re
import json

inputs_pattern = 'data/ordersimple.txt'



def parse_json(element):
    row = json.loads(element)
    return row


with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
     order= (
      pipeline
      | 'Take in Dataset' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(inputs_pattern)
      | beam.Map(parse_json)
      |beam.Map(print)
      | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        'project:test.ordersimple' ,
        schema=table_schema,
        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
         method="STREAMING_INSERTS")

    )
```

But I am getting error like this

```
{'id': 1, 'name': 'A', 'status': 'ACTIVE'}
{'id': 2, 'name': 'B', 'status': 'ACTIVE'}
{'id': 3, 'name': 'C', 'status': 'ACTIVE'}
WARNING:apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery:There were errors inserting to BigQuery. Will retry. Errors were [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': '', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': ''}]}, {'index': 1, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': '', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': ''}]}, {'index': 2, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': '', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': ''}]}]
WARNING:apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery:There were errors inserting to BigQuery. Will retry. Errors were [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': '', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': ''}]}, {'index': 1, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': '', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': ''}]}, {'index': 2, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': '', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': ''}]}]
WARNING:apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery:There were errors inserting to BigQuery. Will retry. Errors were [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': '', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': ''}]}, {'index': 1, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': '', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': ''}]}, {'index': 2, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': '', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': ''}]}]
```

If you see in log,the records are  dictionary,how the write method expects.But, getting error.